# How can I list all files I created?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I would like to get a list of all files in the current revision that were initially created by me. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach that's a bit more direct.

```
for f in `hg locate`; do hg log -r "first(follow('$f'))" --template "$f: {author}\n"; done
```

Translation:

```
for each file
  follow its history to the beginning
    print the filename and author
```

To simply get a list of files first introduced by Bob:

```
for f in `hg locate`; do hg log -r "first(follow('$f')) and author(bob)" --template "$f\n"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it on unix or mac:

```
for therev in $(hg log --template '{rev}\n' --rev 'author("ry4an")') ; do
   hg status --added --no-status --change $therev
done
```

I'm afraid I've no idea how you'd do it on developer-unfriendly OSes.  That gets all files you ever added, so you'd need to compare with `hg manifest` if you wanted to remove files that aren't in the current `tip` revision.

Comment: 1. It's only added by author, not fileset `x and tip-files` 2. "Added by author" in one hg command with revsets (TBD!) `hg log -r "author('bream') and adds('**.*')" --template "{file_adds}\n"`

Comment: @LazyBadger you should make that an actual answer so I can vote for it.

Comment: it's *minimally complex* part of answer, and only **untested part** - I still can't get fileset from templatized log output in order to finally get `hg locate "set:added-by-user and in-tip"`

Comment: heh, developer-unfriendly, oh I can start a holy war about THAT (and I use and like ubuntu daily). You should try powershell sometime, it really blows most linux shells I've seen away in terms of power and discoverability. Like ruby/python but actually meant to be a shell. Anyways, thanks for the answer, definitely +1